# Emergency Mode after Resizing my Home Partition

Tags: boot, grub2, resize

I am desperately searching for help.
I have Ubuntu 18.04 running on a SSD with 4 Partitions
sdb1 = linux = system
sdb2 = swap = swap
sdb3 = linux = ~ mountpoint /home 
sdb4 = ntfs = Exchange to windows / use the rest pf the space as usb drive

I formated sdb4 and decreased its size. Afterwards I was able to boot ubuntu normally. When I resized the sdb3 from a live usb of gparted, I coudlnt boot ubuntu normally afterwards. Stating it is in emergency mode.

I tried reinstalling grub in gpatted live. For that I mounted sdb1 and ran sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sdb

However resulting in a break with error (grub can only be installed in thjs setup by using blocklist).

Do you have a recommendation how I can fix it? I tried the save mode in the advanced grub options but it doesnt seem to work properly since I cant select the options i want after save mode started

I would be relly gratefull if you could help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This error (grub can only be installed in thjs setup by using blocklist) may be because your disk has GPT (GUID Partition Table). You have to create a 1  MB partition  in the begining of disk with flag 'bios_grub'. Now install grub.

   ```
   sudo grub-install /dev/sdb ### or whichever disk you want to install grub on
   ```
2. The UUID of your partition might have changed, compare the UUID of /home entry in etc/fstab with the output of command:

   ```
   sudo blkid  /dev/sdb3 ### partition that you have resized.
   ```

   if changed replace with the new UUID.
3. Run command:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

   and reboot.

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion 2 seems to have fixed it